# MFC CImageList DeleteImageList() vs Remove()

Tags: mfc, imagelist

Someone had some clean up code that looked like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < m_pDragImage->GetImageCount();i++) {
  m_pDragImage->Remove(i);
}
m_pDragImage->DeleteImageList();
delete m_pDragImage;
```

Now I know the remove loop is wrong and should have been:

```
for (int i = 0; i < m_pDragImage->GetImageCount();) {
  if (!m_pDragImage->Remove(i)) {
    i++;
  }
}
```

But now the question is, what is the difference between `Remove()` everything in a loop vs calling `DeleteImageList()` ?    The way I understand it, when you `Add()` something it just saves the bitmap representation of it so you can destroy handles after `Add()`.   So to me, the `Remove()` would seem to clean up everything itself, so not sure if `DeleteImageList()` would be needed in that case?  Or better, not bother with the loop and just use `DeleteImageList()`, or better yet, the object does it on destruction?

TIA!!

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cimagelist-class?view=vs-2017&redirectedfrom=MSDN#deleteimagelist) and use `DeleteImageList`.

Comment: The documentation doesn't explain it at all.

Comment: `CImageList` has automatic cleanup, as do other MFC classes, and most c++ classes for that matter. Calling `delete imagelist_object` is sufficient. Just make sure the image list is no longer used. `DeleteImageList` is exposed in case you want to reuse the pointer. `Remove` is exposed in case you keep adding/removing elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**DeleteImageList()** and **Remove()** each element are doing same thing.

`CImageList::Remove()` and `CImageList::DeleteImageList()` calls `ImageList_Remove();` and `ImageList_Destroy()` Win API functions respectively.

As per [Creating and Destroying Image Lists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/image-lists#creating-and-destroying-image-lists):

> When you no longer need an image list, you can destroy it by
>   specifying its handle in a call to the `ImageList_Destroy` function.

and [Adding and Removing Images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/image-lists#adding-and-removing-images):

> The `ImageList_Remove` function removes an image from an image list.

This might be the reason (assumption) why, MFC don't have wrapper around **`ImageList_RemoveAll()`** because MFC already have function **`DeleteImageList()`** to delete complete list.

Comment: It's better to remove the whole list in one step than removing each member separately.